# Concatenating weights in Keras custom layer using `add_weight` fails while computing gradients

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

While writing a custom layer, I need to have multiple weight matrices concatenated together. If I do this in the `build` function I get the error `ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable:...`, however, if I make a list of wights in `build` and concatenate them in `call` it works. Here is the minimal code to produce the error:

```py
class MultiInputLinear(Layer):
    def __init__(self, output_dim=32, n_inputs=2):
        super(Linear, self).__init__()
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        self.n_inputs = n_inputs


    def build(self, input_shapes):
        self.input_dim = input_shapes[0][1]

        self.W = tf.concat(
            [
                self.add_weight(
                    name=f'W_{i}',
                    shape=(self.input_dim, self.output_dim),
                    initializer='random_normal',
                    trainable=True
                ) for i in range(self.n_inputs)
            ], axis=0
        )

    def call(self, inputs):  
        supports = tf.concat(inputs, axis=-1)        
        return tf.matmul(supports, self.W)

N = 100
A = [np.random.normal(size=(N, N)) for _ in range(2)]
y = np.random.binomial(1, .1, size=(N, 32))

A_in = [Input(batch_size=N, shape=(N, )) for _ in range(2)]
Y = MultiInputLinear(y.shape[1], 2)(A_in)

model = Model(inputs=A_in, outputs=Y)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam())

model.fit(A, y, batch_size=N)
```

However, if in `build` I preserve a list like this:

```py
self.W_list = [
                self.add_weight(
                    name=f'W_{i}',
                    shape=(self.input_dim, self.output_dim),
                    initializer='random_normal',
                    trainable=True
                ) for i in range(self.n_inputs)
            ]
```

and then inside `call` I concatenate them, like the following, there would be no problem:

```py
    def call(self, inputs):  
        supports = tf.concat(inputs, axis=-1)
        W = tf.concat(self.W_list, axis=0)

        return tf.matmul(supports, W)
```

I was wondering what would be the cause of this.

Comment: This is an interesting behavior, and maybe even worth [reporting to the devs](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues), although it may very well be that they are aware of it and it is an expected (if somewhat surprising) behavior. Without knowing the details, I think what happens is that the weights returned by `add_weight` are of a [`Trackable`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.2.0/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py#L529-L536) type that is "tracked" for training. When you concatenate them like that, the Python objects are deleted and so the tracking is lost.